# Custom Vue directive to omit tag but render tag's contents?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to create a custom Vue directive to omit the tag but render the tag's contents when the directive is true.

So for example, if the data for my vue instance is defined as

```
 data:{
    omitIt: true
 }
```

And if the markup looks like this:

```
 <div v-omit="omitIt" class="someClass">
      Hello world!
 </div>
```

When `omitIt` is set to false as it is above, I'd like the following rendered into the dom:

```
<div class="someClass">
      Hello world!
 </div>
```

But when `omitIt` is true I'd like only the following rendered into the dom:

```
Hello world!
```

I initially tried to solve this by doing the following (admittedly not a custom vue directive):

```
 <template v-if="!omitIt">
      <div class="someClass">
  </template>
  Hello world!
  <template v-if="!omitIt">
      </div>
  </template>
```

The above isn't pretty but I thought perhaps it would work.  But alas what gets rendered into the dom when `omitIt` is false is:

```
 <div class="someClass"></div>
 Hello world!
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the results I'm looking for?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Conditionally apply a class?

Comment: No, I want to conditionally render markup around a set of content and control that rendering via vue.  (I can achieve this via backend code but I want to achieve it via vue on the front end if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought @Nit's answer was a great and simple one and upvoted it, but it does have one flaw: a slot may not be a root element so the component will fail when the wrapper needs to be omitted. This is because slots can contain more than one element and if the slot *does* contain more than one, there could end up being more than one root element, which is not allowed.

I have a **partial solution** that renders just the *first* element in the slot if the component should *not* wrap.

```
Vue.component("wrapper", {
  props:{
    nowrap: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  },
  render(h){
    // This will *only* render the *first* element contained in 
    // the default slot if `nowrap` is set. This is because a component
    // *must* have a single root element
    if (this.nowrap) return this.$slots.default[0]
    // Otherwise, wrap the contents in a DIV and render the contents
    return h('div', this.$slots.default)
  }
})
```

Here is an example of it working.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("wrapper", {
  props:{
    nowrap: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  },
  render(h){
    // Log a warning if content is being omitted
    const omissionMessage = "Wrapper component contains more than one root node with nowrap specified. Only the first node will be rendered."
    if (this.$slots.default.length > 1 && this.nowrap)
      console.warn(omissionMessage)
    
    // This will *only* render the *first* element contained in 
    // the default slot if `nowrap` is set. This is because a component
    // *must* have a single root element
    if (this.nowrap) return this.$slots.default[0]
    
    // Otherwise, wrap the contents in a DIV and render the contents
    return h('div', this.$slots.default)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.someClass{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <wrapper class="someClass">Hello World</wrapper>
  <wrapper nowrap>No wrap, single root</wrapper> <br>
  <wrapper nowrap>
    No wrap, two roots. Paragraph is ommitted.
    <p>Some other content</p>
  </wrapper>
</div>
```

A couple notes: The component will always wrap unless you add `nowrap` as an attribute. Also, notice the class is added to the wrapped container without specifying it as a prop. This is because Vue automatically renders attributes that aren't specified as props on the root element of a component, unless you tell it not to.

Comment: This is a nice solution, I considered rendering functions myself, but hoped I could do it without them.

Comment: @Nit I thought your idea was great and I like using a component for this; I wish it did work.

Comment: These answers have taught me a lot.  Seeing two people which such high reputations have difficulty accomplishing a full solution is telling me that if there is another way to code my page without this feature, that might be the better approach.  Thank you for helping me see that.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is **wrong**, slots cannot be used in this manner. Please see [Bert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202669/1470607) instead.

---

The easiest solution would be to create a wrapper component with [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) for this purpose, passing the omitting argument as a prop.
The content distribution part becomes rather straightforward.

In the wrapper component template:

```
<slot v-if="omitIt"></slot>
<div v-else>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Wherever you want to use the wrapper:

```
<wrapper v-bind:omitIt="omitIt">
  // Content
</wrapper>
```

Comment: Seems like that would work pretty good but is there a way to get the div to render with `class="someClass"` if that's set on the wrapper tag?

Comment: @RonC The easiest option would be to pass those with a prop as well. Note that while you *can*, it's bad practice to call that prop `class`, as it would overlap with the default behavior. It's better to name it something else.

Comment: Also, I don't think this actually works. A slot cannot be a root node. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/QqwbEE?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert Sadly, it turns out you're correct. I wrote the answer off the top of my head without testing it first. If you have an alternative approach, it would be great if you could write up an answer.

Comment: @RonC Sorry for the inconvenience in that regard, would you please remove the accepted answer mark from this answer?

Comment: @Nit No worries, your answer made sense to me and I hadn't had a chance to implement it yet.  Bit I totally knew a component can have only have one root node and but it just didn't occur to me in my excitement to have a possible approach.  :-)  Still your answer taught me something about slots which is very useful.